# Split array into two array and looping them in two HTML table

Tags: php, html, arrays

i have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32021
            [nama_mk] =>  Matematika Ekonomi
            [semester] => 1
            [jum_sks] => 3
            [nilai] => A 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32022
            [nama_mk] =>  Teori Ekonomi Mikro
            [semester] => 2
            [jum_sks] => 2
            [nilai] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32040
            [nama_mk] =>  Teori Ekonomi Mikro
            [semester] => 3
            [jum_sks] => 2
            [nilai] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32051
            [nama_mk] =>  Dasar Akuntansi I
            [semester] => 1
            [jum_sks] => 3
            [nilai] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32052
            [nama_mk] =>  Dasar Akuntansi Lanjutan
            [semester] => 2
            [jum_sks] => 3
            [nilai] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [kode_mk] => KD.32060
            [nama_mk] =>  Akuntansi Perbankan
            [semester] => 4
            [jum_sks] => 3
            [nilai] => 
        )
)
```

how to split them into two arrays and looping them to two html tables...?

Comment: Split cause of what criterias?

Comment: no criteria...just split them into 2 tables...i have one array with 60 values within....so i want to split them into 2 array with 30 values each array..so i can looping them into 2 tables

Comment: So array_chunk() is what you're looking for, like @Wayne Whitty mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the function [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)?

> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may
>   contain less than size elements.

```
$mySplitArray = array_chunk($array, 3);
var_dump($mySplitArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

go through with foreach()

```
foreach($parentArray as $parent)
{
   foreach($parent as $child)
    {
        echo '<table>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td> ' . $child['kode_mk'] . ' </td>';
        echo '<td> ' . $child['nama_mk'] . ' </td>';
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear by what you mean for "split into two arrays", but for what I would do here:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    //Start of table row
    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        //work with keys/values
    }
}
```